# Rails nested attributes and has_many :through associations not showing fields_for

Tags: devise, nested-forms, nested-attributes

Here are my Models:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :roles, :dependent => :destroy, :inverse_of => :user
  has_many :users, :through => :roles
  validates :name, presence: true

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :roles, :dependent => :destroy, :inverse_of => :user
  has_many :companies, :through => :roles
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :roles, :limit => 1, :allow_destroy => true

end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user, :inverse_of => :roles
  belongs_to :company, :inverse_of => :roles

  #accepts_nested_attributes_for :companies, :limit => 1, :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company

end
```

The idea here is that Companies are unique and Users can be associated to multiple companies via a Role.  I set up devise on the User model for authentication and signup. That was working fine and I could signup as a new user.

I want to add the company name to the signup process.  I am trying a nested form:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :html => {:class => "form-signin" }, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <%= render partial: "shared/flash" %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>
    <h1 class="form-signin-heading text-muted">Register</h1>
    <%= f.email_field :email, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Email", autofocus: true %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Password", autocomplete: "off" %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Password Confirmation", autocomplete: "off" %>

    <%= f.fields_for :roles do |r| %>
    <%= r.fields_for :company do |c| %>
          <%= c.text_field :name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Company", autocomplete: "off" %>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">
        Register
    </button>
<% end %>
```

I found some other SA answers that pointed out the need for the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to be drilled down though the `has_many` through associations as well as some single/plural issues.  After fixing those my form loads without errors except that the `fields_for` block is empty.

Now I will admit my models may be the issue here.  I have copied the code from an app I worked on a few years ago so I have of lost track of why I did it this way.

At the end of the day I want to create the Company and Role when the user signs up.  I planned to add the creation of the Role to the Company controller but I need to get to at least creating the company first.

**UPDATE**

I did some more digging and updated my form to this:

```
    <% company = resource.companies.build %>
    <%= f.fields_for :company, company do |c| %>
          <%= c.text_field :name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Company", autocomplete: "off" %>
    <% end %>
```

I realized that my Devise controller was not building the nested Company resource.  I wanted to stay away from a custom Devise controller.  My form submits and my user is created but I am missing something here still because the Company and Role are not getting saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging and experimentation here is how I resolved this:

**Models**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :roles, :dependent => :destroy, :inverse_of => :user
  has_many :companies, :through => :roles
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :roles, :limit => 1, :allow_destroy => true

end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :inverse_of => :roles
  belongs_to :company, :inverse_of => :roles
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles, :dependent => :destroy, :inverse_of => :user
  has_many :users, :through => :roles
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

**Custom Devise Registration Controller**

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

    # GET /resource/sign_up
  def new
    build_resource({})
    @role = resource.roles.build(role: "owner", active: 1, default_role: 1)
    @company = @role.build_company
    set_minimum_password_length
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with self.resource
  end

  protected

  def sign_up_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, roles_attributes: [ company_attributes: [ :id, :name ] ] )
  end

end
```

**HTML**

```
<%= form_for(resource, :html => {:class => "form-signin" }, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <%= render partial: "shared/flash" %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>
    <h1 class="form-signin-heading text-muted">Register</h1>
    <%= f.email_field :email, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Email", autofocus: true %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Password", autocomplete: "off" %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Password Confirmation", autocomplete: "off" %>

    <%= f.fields_for :roles, resource.roles.build do |r| %>
    <%= r.fields_for :company, resource.roles.build.build_company do |c| %>
          <%= c.text_field :name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Company", autocomplete: "off" %>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>

    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">
        Register
    </button>
<% end %>
```

I figured I had the models and associations messed up.  Now the `form_for` works it's magic.

I am going to post another separate question but when I still can't figure out is:

- Why does the @role and @company I set in the controller work in the view HTML?
- How can I set the additional Role attributes? I tried during the build stage in both the controller and the view but it doesn't take.